# optimize python code to read file

Tags: python, optimization, file-handling

I have the following code:
Code 1:

```
logfile = open(logfile, 'r')
logdata = logfile.read()
logfile.close()
CurBeginA = BeginSearchDVar
CurEndinA = EndinSearchDVar
matchesBegin = re.search(str(BeginTimeFirstEpoch), logdata)
matchesEnd = re.search(str(EndinTimeFirstEpoch), logdata)
BeginSearchDVar = BeginTimeFirstEpoch
EndinSearchDVar = EndinTimeFirstEpoch
```

And I also have this code in another part of the script: Code 2

```
TheTimeStamps = [ x.split(' ')[0][1:-1] for x in open(logfile).readlines() ]
```

It is clear here that I'm loading up the log file twice. I want to avoid that.  Is there anyway I can do what I'm doing in code 2, in code 1?  So, that way, the log file is loaded up only once?

In Code 1, I'm searching the log to ensure two very specific patterns are found in it on different lines.

In Code 2, I am pulling only the first column of all lines in the log file.

How can this be better optimized? I'm running this on a log file that's currently 480MB in size and the script completes in about 12 seconds.  Considering this log can get up to 1GB or even 2GB in size, I'd like to make this as efficient as possible.

**Update:**

So the code from @abernert works.  I went ahead and added an extra logic to it, and now, it's no longer working. Below is the modified code I now have.  What I'm basically doing here is, if the patterns in matchesBegin and matchesEnd are found in the log, then, search the log from matchesBegin to matchesEnd and print out only lines that contain stringA and stringB:

```
        matchesBegin, matchesEnd = None, None
        beginStr, endStr = str(BeginTimeFirstEpoch).encode(), str(EndinTimeFirstEpoch).encode()
        AllTimeStamps = []
        mylist = []
        with open(logfile, 'rb') as input_data:
            def SearchFirst():
                matchesBegin, matchesEnd = None, None
                for line in input_data:
                    if not matchesBegin:
                        matchesBegin = beginStr in line
                    if not matchesEnd:
                        matchesEnd = endStr in line
                return(matchesBegin, matchesEnd)
            matchesBegin, matchesEndin = SearchFirst()
            #print type(matchesBegin)
            #print type(matchesEndin)
            #if str(matchesBegin) == "True" and str(matchesEnd) == "True":
            if matchesBegin is True and matchesEndin is True:
                rangelines = 0
                for line in input_data:
                    print line
                    if beginStr in line[0:25]:  # Or whatever test is needed
                        rangelines += 1
                        #print line.strip()
                        if re.search(stringA, line) and re.search(stringB, line):
                            mylist.append((line.strip()))
                        break
                for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
                    print line
                    if endStr in line[0:25]:
                        rangelines += 1
                        if re.search(stringA, line) and re.search(stringB, line):
                            mylist.append((line.strip()))
                        break
                    if re.search(stringA, line) and re.search(stringB, line):
                        rangelines += 1
                        mylist.append((line.strip()))
                    else:
                        rangelines += 1
                #return(mylist,rangelines)
                    print(mylist,rangelines)
                    AllTimeStamps.append(line.split(' ')[0][1:-1])
```

What did I do wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is almost never a good reason to call `readlines()`. A file is already an iterable of lines, so you can just loop over the file; reading all of those lines into memory and building a giant list of them is just wasting time and memory.

Calling `read()`, on the other hand, can sometimes be useful. It *does* have to read the entire thing into memory as one giant string, but doing a regex search over a giant string can speed things up enough, compared to searching line by line, that the wasted time and space is more than compensated for.

But if you want to reduce this to a single pass over the file, since you already have to iterate line by line, there really is no other option but to also do the regex searches line by line. This should *work* (you haven't shown your patterns, but based on the names, I'm guessing that they aren't expected to cross line boundaries, and aren't multiline or dotall patterns), but whether it's actually faster or slower will depend on all kinds of factors.

At any rate, it's certainly worth trying, to *see* if it helps. (And, while we're at it, I'm going to use a `with` statement to make sure you close the file, instead of leaking it as you do in your second part.)

```
CurBeginA = BeginSearchDVar
CurEndinA = EndinSearchDVar
BeginSearchDVar = BeginTimeFirstEpoch
EndinSearchDVar = EndinTimeFirstEpoch    
matchesBegin, matchesEnd = None, None
TheTimeStamps = []
with open(logfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not matchesBegin:
            matchesBegin = re.search(str(BeginTimeFirstEpoch), line)
        if not matchesEnd:
            matchesEnd = re.search(str(EndinTimeFirstEpoch), line)
        TheTimeStamps.append(line.split(' ')[0][1:-1])
```

---

There are a few other minor changes you can make here that might help.

---

I don't know what `BeginTimeFirstEpoch` is, but the fact that you're using `str(BeginTimeFirstEpoch)` implies that it's not a regex pattern at all, but something like a `datetime` object or an `int`? And that you don't really need the match objects, you just need to know whether there *is* a match? If so, you can drop the `regex` and do a plain substring search, which is a bit faster:

```
matchesBegin, matchesEnd = None, None
beginStr, endStr = str(BeginTimeFirstEpoch), str(EndinTimeFirstEpoch)
with …
    # …
    if not matchesBegin:
        matchesBegin = beginStr in line
    if not matchesEnd:
        matchesEnd = endStr in line
```

---

If your search strings and timestamps and so on are all pure ASCII, it might be faster to work on the file in binary mode, only decoding the bits you need to store, instead of everything:

```
matchesBegin, matchesEnd = None, None
beginStr, endStr = str(BeginTimeFirstEpoch).encode(), str(EndinTimeFirstEpoch).encode()
with open(logFile, 'rb') as f:
    # …
    if not matchesBegin:
        matchesBegin = beginStr in line
    if not matchesEnd:
        matchesEnd = endStr in line
    TheTimeStamps.append(line.split(b' ')[0][1:-1].decode())
```

---

Finally, I doubt `str.split` is anywhere near a bottleneck in your code, but, just in case… why bother splitting on all spaces when we only want the first split?

```
TheTimeStamps.append(line.split(b' ', 1)[0][1:-1].decode())
```

Comment: i updated my original post with your suggestions. please review.

Comment: @RoyMWell Your new version is iterating over the file three times. I don't understand why you're doing that, since the whole point was to do everything inside a single loop. And that's what the problem is: after the first `for line in input_data:`, you're at the end of the file. So when you do `for line in input_data:` again, you're getting all the lines from the end of the file to the end of the file—that is, nothing.

Comment: i apologize for the confusion.  i didnt post the full code because i didnt want to scare away potential users that may be able to help.  the ultimate goal here is to be able to know if the strings in matchesBegin and matchesEnd are found, and if found, print out entries from the logs that are between those two strings. Question is, how can your suggestions be merged with mine to accomplish this? again, i'm sincerely sorry for the confusion.